# PostgreSQL connecting two tables with 2 common attributes on Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 entities; castfilm and staff in my erd that  have a common attribute employeeid. Now, I wanted to Query in postgre to show the attributes that are related to the specific person that has an employeeid no. 307 where his fname and lname is David and Kaye respectively.

My erd looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Atae.png)

The attributes that I wanted to show are fname, lname, castrole, filmtitle, filmgenre, filmyear, companyname, staffposition, artistname and soundtitle that are related to the film of the employee named David Kaye

Here's my query:

```
SELECT distinct fname,lname,castrole, filmtitle, filmgenre, filmyear, companyname
FROM employee,
     castfilm,
     film,
     production,
     company
 WHERE employee.employeeid = 307
   AND employee.employeeid = castfilm.employeeid 
   AND castfilm.filmid = film.filmid 
   AND production.companyid = company.companyid 
   AND production.filmid = film.filmid
```

[output][2]

How do I show the other staffs and casts that are related to the specific movie that David Kaye is on?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! (Easier to write - without errors, easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`statement:

> The argument of EXISTS is an arbitrary SELECT statement, or subquery.
>   The subquery is evaluated to determine whether it returns any rows. If
>   it returns at least one row, the result of EXISTS is "true"; if the
>   subquery returns no rows, the result of EXISTS is "false".

In the subquery you should check if for given `filmid` there exists an `employeeid` in `castfilm`. And this `employeeid` should be 307.

Like this:

```
SELECT distinct fname,lname,castrole, filmtitle, filmgenre, filmyear, companyname
FROM employee,
     castfilm,
     film,
     production,
     company
 WHERE employee.employeeid = castfilm.employeeid 
   AND castfilm.filmid = film.filmid 
   AND production.companyid = company.companyid 
   AND production.filmid = film.filmid
   AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
        employeeid
    FROM
        castfilm
    WHERE
        filmid = film.filmid AND
        employeeid = 307
    );
```

Please, note that `film.filmid` is used in the subquery.

Furthermore, as @jarlh noted, you could use `JOIN` syntax, like this:

```
SELECT
    fname,
    lname,
    castrole,
    filmtitle,
    filmgenre,
    filmyear,
    companyname
FROM
    employee
    JOIN castfilm
    ON (employee.employeeid = castfilm.employeeid)
    JOIN film
    ON (castfilm.filmid = film.filmid)
    JOIN production
    ON (film.filmid = production.filmid)
    JOIN company
    ON (production.companyid = company.companyid)
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            employeeid
        FROM
            castfilm
        WHERE
            filmid = film.filmid AND
            employeeid = 307
    );
```

Comment: This looks like it'd be a good candidate for NATURAL JOINs, too. That may help simplify the logic even more.

Comment: tnx for answering but the pic of my erd didnt work but i fixed it now i mean to actually show the staff position of an employee as well..more details about that is

Comment: i mean to actually show the staff position of an employee as well...the thing is my staffposition attribute can have no value at all for ex. "David Kaye is a cast which means he plays a castrole but he does not have a staffposition because he is not a director or a writer." however theres cases where an employee may have both a castrole and a staffposition. so i intend to show  rows based of david kaye that has (fname, lname, castrole, filmtitle, filmgenre, filmyear, companyname, staffposition, artistname and soundtitle)